# SurveyMonkey survey as in-page overlay/modal/lightbox

Tags: modal-dialog, overlay, lightbox, surveymonkey

I've searched the SurveyMonkey website, both help... and developer..., as well as the general net and stackoverflow, and can't find any examples of a SurveyMonkey survey being displayed in an in-page overlay (referred to by some as a "lightbox" or modal).

I think what I need to use is SurveyMonkey's Embed option, as opposed to Invitation or Survey Popups:

http://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/How-do-I-embed-a-survey-or-have-it-open-in-a-popup-window-on-my-site

I'd like that overlay div to appear, close, etc upon the same triggers as a regular survey would/could, that is open if the user has no previous SurveyMonkey cookie, close when completed or closed by user, etc.

I can probably hack through a solution by forcing the survey into a custom overlay I build, but the behaviors would be more tricky, probably having to read the SurveyMonkey cookie, I suppose.  Or, perhaps I could check for certain IDs of SurveyMonkey content that exists at various stages to pull off the behaviors (but I'll have to look at the generated code throughout the process to know if this is an option).

In short, it seems like someone else has surely run into this issue before and likely that a solution has already been created, at least partial to save me some time.  I just can't find it.

Here are some things I found on the embed itself:

https://www.surveymonkey.com/blog/en/blog/2013/04/23/how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/ 
https://www.surveymonkey.com/blog/en/blog/2013/04/16/video-tutorial-how-to-embed-your-survey-on-a-website/

Any and all help much appreciated, pointers/resources, example code, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: This would be a lot of work to hack together, but it may be possible.

SurveyMonkey's popup invitation feature is blocked by most users' browsers and is old-fashioned. Modals are the way of the future.

Comment: Due to cross-domain issues, this ended up not being do-able as far as I could tell.  The concept was abandoned by Client.